# how to pass js variable to php via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello I am new to js and I stuck on the problem about passing variables to php via ajax.

```
 <script>
            $date = "123";
            $.ajax({
                url: './record.php', 
                type: "POST",
                dataType:'text', 
                data: ({'date': date}),
                success: function(data){
                    console.log("successfully");
                }
            }); 
</script>
```

And below is my code in record.php file.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST['date'])){
    //$hello = 'hh';
    $_SESSION['date'] = $_POST['date'];
    echo($_SESSION['date']);
}else{
    echo "its empty(var)";
}

?>
```

Page always print out "its empty(var)" and I checked console, it shows "successfully"... I already stayed on this problem for several hours and looked for a lot of similar post, but I still can't find where is the problem. Can anyone have a look at it? I also already loaded the jQuery library.

Comment: That's just a typo. You're setting a variable named `$date`, but are sending a variable named `date`.

Answer (score 2):

you ar mixing js variable with php variable, js variables are declared with `var` and php variables are declared with `$fieldname`

```
<script>
            var date = "123";
            $.ajax({
                url: './record.php', 
                type: "POST",
                dataType:'text', 
                data: {'date': date},
                success: function(data){
                    console.log("successfully");
                }
            }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Does the var statement matter in a non-strict environment? --- Ah. It does when the second date doesn't match the first...

Comment: yes because or else how will it understand its a js variable or not

Comment: forgot the ; after it, try now

Comment: @Exprator of course it does http://jsbin.com/rudomihifu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You're correct though, the OP was passing an undefined `date` variable, because they defined it as `$date`.

Comment: I got wrong input, added ";" back but still the main problem.

Comment: you are not getting the value in the php page right?? make sure the path is correct, try to keep the php page in the same folder and change the url to  url: 'record.php', and check

Answer (score 0):

if you want a PHP variable insite javascript you should define php variable first then asign it into js.

```
<?php $date = "123"; ?>';

<script>

            var date=<?php echo $date; ?>';
            $.ajax({
                url: './record.php', 
                type: "POST",
                dataType:'text', 
                data: ({'date': date}),
                success: function(data){
                    console.log("successfully");
                }
            }); 
</script>
```

Hope it wil helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You cant mix server (php) and client (js)

you might to this

```
<?php $var = 0?>
```

then in html you create

`<input id="something" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $var?>">`

then you get that value via

`document.getElementById("something").value;`

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `$date` and pass in your ajax as `date`.

Try this:

```
<script>
        var date = "123";
        $.ajax({
            url: './record.php', 
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'text', 
            data: {'date': date},
            success: function(data){
                console.log("successfully");
            }
        }); 
</script>
```